# I want to extract the data present in JSON file from a odata url but i am unable to extract the content using a loop

Tags: arrays, json, json.net, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Below is the JSON file which i am referring..

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://ac.com/odata/$metadata#ModelVariableDataTypes(Id,ModelVariable,DoubleValues,ModelVariable(Id,Name,UnitOfMeasure,UnitOfMeasure(Name,Abbreviation)),DoubleValues(Id,Value,Timestamp,DataQuality,DataQuality(Id,Name)))",
  "@odata.count": 1,
  "value": [
    {
      "Id": 1928155,
      "ModelVariable": {
        "Id": 1929663,
        "Name": "AccCore_CPULoadProcess",
        "UnitOfMeasure": {
          "Name": "%",
          "Abbreviation": "%"
        }
      },
      "DoubleValues": [
        {
          "Id": 75865549,
          "Value": 0.0,
          "Timestamp": "2018-09-25T03:35:00Z",
          "DataQuality": {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "Good"
          }
        },
        {
          "Id": 75865729,
          "Value": 0.0,
          "Timestamp": "2018-09-25T03:40:00Z",
          "DataQuality": {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "Good"
          }
        },
        {
          "Id": 75865873,
          "Value": 0.0,
          "Timestamp": "2018-09-25T03:45:00Z",
          "DataQuality": {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "Good"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to extract the data present in JSON file from a odata url but i am unable to extract the content using a loop as in the JSON file the odata count is mentioned as 1(@odata.count": 1) so when i am trying to catch the entire data using a loop it is not working.

I want to extract the data present in the array field of doublevalues and wanted to show the output of the top three values of CPU process.

I am trying with the below code to extract the JSON data.

```
$path= "C:\Users\s.papolu\Desktop\mem.json"
$data = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\S.Papolu\Desktop\mem.json' | ConvertFrom-Json 

$maxCount = $data.'@odata.count'
$maxCount

@"
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $maxCount; $i++)
{
$Name = $("{0:N1}" -f $data.value.ModelVariable.Name)
$cpu = $("{$i`:N2}" -f $data.value.DoubleValues.Value)
}

write-host $Name,$cpu
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking here. For one thing, you've got an extraneous at-sign and double-quote in there.

MaxCount is just 1 here, so the loop only runs once. For each item, though, are you trying to store the results in some structure and then show it? Which of the DoubleValues do you want? The top three?

Is this *closer* to what you want?

```
$data = Get-Content -Path $path | ConvertFrom-Json

$maxCount = $data.'@odata.count'
$maxCount

$results = @()

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $maxCount; $i++)
{
    # get the top three doubles values
    $Doubles = @($data.value[$i].DoubleValues | sort -Property Value -Descending | select -first 3)

    $results += [PsCustomObject]@{
        Name = $data.value[$i].ModelVariable[0].Name;
        Cpu = $Doubles;
    }
}

$results | ft
```

Comment: Are you still working on it? If so, if you can explain the differences between what it did and what you expect, perhaps I could fix it...?